# Accessing the value of an observable inside a plain JS array in Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

#### Background

I have a plain JS array, initially empty. I later populate it with values. The values sent to it are numbers that are Knockout observables. Later, I want to compare those values to values in another, knockout observable array. My problem is that whenever I pass the index of the current item in my array loop, and pass that index value (a number!), the array returns a function. To get an idea, look at the JS that follows.

Note that my project and actual script is viewable on JSBin. Further, to view the problem in the console, you have to add assignments, then press 'sort'.

> **JSBin**:  [http://jsbin.com/fehoq/177/edit]](http://jsbin.com/fehoq/177/edit%5d)[1](http://jsbin.com/fehoq/175/edit)

#### JS

```
//example script that follows actual script

var _this = this;

//initialize my array
this. lowest = [];

// I want to compare values in lowest to values in this array
this.scores = ko.observableArray();

// method that does comparison
this.myMethod = function(){

    // initialize my helper, k
    var k;  
     ...

    // loop through one array
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.scores(), function (score) {

        // make sure my value is a number...
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(score()))) {

           // this is important, I need to current index for comparison
           k = _this.scores.indexOf(score);
           console.log(k);

           // this is where things break - it prints a function, not a value!
           console.log(_this.lowest[k]);

           // useless check, the value is a function, so they're always different
           if (score()!=_this.lowest[k]){
             // do stuff
           }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update

Putting the method I'm using, maybe someone will notice something I missed given that my syntax is correct(?).

```
this.mean = (function(scores,i) {
  var m = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var k;

  ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.scores(), function(score) {

    console.log([typeof score(), score()]);

    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(score()))) {

      console.log(i);
      console.log(_this.lowest[i]);

      if (score() != _this.lowest[i]) {
        m += parseFloat(score());
        count += 1;
      }

    }

  });

 if (count) {
    m = m / count;
    return m.toFixed(2);
  } else {
    return 'N/A';
  }
});
}
```

#### Update 2

Just in case someone else wanders over here since my problem isn't solve still. The following code is how I set the value of `lowest`:

```
this.dropLowestScores = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.students(), function(student){
        var comparator = function(a,b){
          if(a()<b()){
            return 1;
          } else if(a() > b()){
            return -1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        };       
        var tmp = student.scores().slice(0);
        tmp.sort(comparator);
        student.lowest = ko.observableArray(tmp.splice((tmp.length-2),tmp.length-1));
    });
};
```

#### Outstanding Questions, 5/9/2014

1. Jeremy's script runs but without the desired effects. For example, `console.log(_this.lowest[k])` prints `undefined`, just as mine does. Further, the matched scores aren't skipped, which they should be.
2. Jeremy's script specifies `lowest` as a ko.observable. My script also now has `lowest` as a ko.observable, but why shouldn't a plain JS array work for this? I only need `lowest` to update when the button it's bound to is clicked, and those bindings are already taken care of.

Comment: Supposing you have 2 scores the same. Your index `k` will break. There's an extra param in the method `ko.utils.arrayForEach`... `ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.scores(), function (score,k) {`

Comment: So is _this.lowest your "plain JS array" with observables in it? If so, you need to call the function to get the number out of the observable. However I feel like you know this already so maybe I'm misunderstanding something. _this.lowest[k]() is a function???

Comment: I understand that for knockout, values are retrieved via `myObservable()`. I can't seem to get this to work here though. `k` is a number. `_this.lowest[k]` returns a function. So does `_this.lowest[k]()`, and `_this.lowest[k()]`. I'm missing something syntactically, but I'm not sure what!

Comment: I also haven't had any trouble setting a value for `k`. I run into trouble when I pass it as an index. Again, according to my console log, `k` is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how observables work in Knockout.

When you create one, you are creating a function.

```
var myObservable1 = ko.observable(); // Create it.
var myObservable2 = ko.observable("Hola!"); // Create it with a value.

console.log(typeof myObservable2); // It is indeed a function
console.log(typeof myObservable2()); // That returns a string
console.log(myObservable2()); // And get the value.
```

**EDIT BASED ON QUESTION IN COMMENTS**

```
var koTest = ko.observableArray();
koTest.push("Line0");
koTest.push("Line1");
koTest.push("Line2");
koTest.push("Line3");
koTest.push("Line4");

var jsTest = [];
jsTest.push("Line0");
jsTest.push("Line1");
jsTest.push("Line2");
jsTest.push("Line3");
jsTest.push("Line4");


alert(koTest()[2]);
alert(jsTest[2]);
alert(koTest()[2] === jsTest[2]);
```

**Test Code**

I went ahead and make a runnable test of your code and everything was working just fine for me.  I had to make some assumptions about the contents of `_this` -- in particular the declaration of `lowest`, which I made an `observableArray` based on how you were accessing it.

Anyways, this code runs:

```
    var _this = {
        scores: ko.observableArray(),
        lowest: ko.observableArray()
    };


    var mean = (function(scores) {
        var m = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var k;


        ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.scores(), function(score) {

            console.log([typeof score(), score()]);

            if (!isNaN(parseFloat(score()))) {
                k = _this.scores.indexOf(score);
                console.log(k);
                console.log(_this.lowest[k]);
                if (score() != _this.lowest[k]) {
                    m += parseFloat(score());
                    count += 1;
                }

            }


        });


        if (count) {
            m = m / count;
            return m.toFixed(2);
        } else {
            return 'N/A';
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        _this.scores.push(ko.observable(i));
    }

    var m = mean();
    alert(m);
```

Comment: Ok, I'm with out. Now how do I correctly print the value of an observable at a given index in an array? `jsArray[k]`, `jsArray[k()]`, `jsArray[k]()`, `jsArray()[k]`, `jsArray()[k]()` all return either function or error. FYI, I'm not surprised that all of these don't work, I just have no idea what should.

Comment: @Jefftopia Added example

Comment: This makes complete sense to me, and it is exactly as I would expect. when I do the following, however, `console.log(_this.lowest[k]);`, the console prints a function. You can now view the full, troublesome method in my post.

Comment: Actually, there is a difference between your code and mine, although I am unsure whether it matters. My `jsTest` has observables in it, not plain strings or numbers.

Comment: Test code posted, complete with an array of observable items.

Comment: This is thorough but when I run this on my end I still get `undefined` for `console.log(_this.lowest[k]);`, and my mean does not properly ignore the matched scores.

Comment: This is a different question.  I only focused on the property access of your original question.

Comment: The second part, dropping matched scores, is a separate question, in a sense. But I still cannot access the array value - `undefined`.